# jQuery scroll to element even if window height is small

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, height

I have a page with a logo on top and a form under. There are "Login" and "Join" buttons that when are clicked they expand the respective form. I want when these buttons are clicked to also scroll to these forms which I named them "login" and "join". The problem is that the height of the window is insufficient to make scrolling possible. I was thinking to first modify the body height when the buttons are clicked and then scroll, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// first modify the body height
$('body').height($(window).height() + 1000);

// scroll to the Login button
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#Login').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you so much, I'm learning every day :)